# VScode terminal startup command defined in workspace settings

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nvm

I would like to know if it is possible to run certain a set of initial commands when the VScode terminal startups. Could these commands be defined in the workspace settings of the project?

This is useful when changing between projects using different versions of Node.